# 'Was this post useful' plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm searching for an FAQ plugin, which should have 'was this post useful' option (it can be implemented as a set of plugins as well, not necessary to be all-in-one plugin). Generally FAQ can be implemented as category with posts, but I'll need expand/collapse JS only in that category, and I need the 'was this post useful' option only in that category as well, so I prefer a plugin for it.

Any suggestions?

*Wordpress version: 3.2.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Anyway Feedback](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anyway-feedback/) provides this functionality. It can be enabled per post type, so I've registered custom post type, enabled the feedback for this post type, and registered the category taxonomy, so I can post FAQ questions in any category.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed and released an FAQ Manager for WordPress ([FAQ MANAGER](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-faq-manager/)) that has all the elements other than the "was this useful" portion you're looking for. It uses custom post types and taxonomies to keep the content segregated, so you can apply other functions / plugins if need be.